# Replace a text in the file from the key value pairs in bash

Tags: bash, macos, sed, replace, key-value

I have a text file where I want to make a text replacements using another file, which is structured like that:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
...
```

I am using a bash script for that and I end up with the following solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

index=0
count=$(wc -l $2 | grep -Eo '[0-9]')

until [ $index -eq $count ]; do

    line=$(awk "NR==($index+1)" $2)
    key=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d=)
    value=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d=)
    sed -i '' 's/'"${key}"'/'"${value}"'/g' $1
    index=$(($index+1))

done
```

Basically I am getting number of lines in the mapping file and just iterating through it, splitting each line by a `=` sign and calling a `sed` command. This works fine and does its job, but I wanted to ask if there is a more efficient way to achieve that? Since I am not a big bash expert, I assume that there might be better/more beautiful approach.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's#(.*)=(.*)#s/\1/\2/#p' inputFile | sed -f - textFile
```

Convert the input file into a source of a sed file and pipe it into a second invocation of sed to be acted on a text file.

N.B. Your success may vary if either the key or the value contain characters that may be mistook for sed's metacharacters e.g. contain a `$` or `.` etc etc etc.

Comment: thanks, but my file actually contains `$` and the version that I am posted seems to be working fine with it... this one looks nice (I love bash for single line commands) but for some reason it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Azat beware if sed receives a metacharater in the LHS of a substitution you may get false positive matches e.g. a `.` matches any character including a period.

Comment: ah no, special characters are in the value part, keys do not contain anything like that. And I am confused now since you are mentioned GNU, it is not smth available on the mac right?

Comment: @Azat I believe mac uses a bsd version of sed if you wanted gnu you would have to install it (darwin?). RHS of substitution does however interpret some metacharaters e.g `&` and back references `\n` where `n` is `1-9`. Also perhaps upper/lowercase directives and substitution command delimiter. You may need to **clean** the input file before you use it with your commands above.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a sed script from the file just as is, by prepending with `s/`, changing `=` to `/` and suffixing with `/g`. Then run the generated sed script over the input file.

```
sed "$(sed 's/\(.*\)=\(.*\)/s\/\1\/\2\/g/' "$another_file")" "$text_file"
```

If you are creating templates, this is not a good approuch, in such case go with a template or preprocessor engine - like `envsubst`, `cpp`, `php`, `jinja2`.

Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck.

> I am getting number of lines in the mapping file and just iterating through it, splitting each line by a = sign

Research https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: I didn't get the part about the generation: do you mean that instead of mappings file better to have a script based file? It is not exact what I need since key=value file should be understandable for non tech people (it is still kind of tech but key=value is the simplest thing to explain), and it would be hard to ask them to edit the script file...